# trying to make Toast after Activity gets opened by intent

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-intent, toast

I have an activity which gets called by 2 intents, one after a simple menu-selection and the other way by a intent after a deletion of an item in a database. However, I wanted to display in the called activity a little Toast, but only when it's opened through the intent of the deletion. I thought of following solution

```
public void intentCheck(){
    Log.d("ShowActivity","intentCheck() called");
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null){    
            String check = extras.getString("AdvancedViewActivityCall");
            if(check == "calling"){
                Log.d("ShowActivity","delete-intent succeeded");
                Toast success = new Toast(ShowActivity.this);
                success.makeText(ShowActivity.this, "Deletion succeded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG); 

            }
        }
```

but it doesn't work... somehow, no toast gets displayed.

edit:// i applied success.show(); now, but now i get a RunetimeException O.o ( http://pastebin.com/Th3NY5d0 )

edit: SOLUTION: `Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show(); //seems to be the "static way", which eclipse proposed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `if ("calling".equals(check))` instead of `if(check == "calling")` ?

EDIT: 
try `Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();`

Comment: i even get returned that the "delete-ntent succeeded" like so "calling" = check, it just somehow doesn't start the toast.. eclipse throws me some notice that the static .makeText should be accessed in a static way

Comment: your edit, was it! THANKS! don't really understand it anyway, but it seems to have to do with the eclipse hint of a "static reference"

Comment: Only toasts containing custom views really need to have a `Toast` instance created. Otherwise, using the static `makeText` method is best. I also had this problem in the past.

Answer (score 1):

you have to call show method for toast until otherwise toast will not display.

```
success.show();
```

Comment: lol, i applied success.show(); now, but now getting a RunetimeException